# Display latest value that fullfills LOOKUP-criteria if range contains empty cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
   |      A     |      B        |     C
---|------------|---------------|----------
1  |    O.K.    |    O.K.       |
2  |    Error1  |    Error1     |
3  |    O.K.    |    O.K.       |
4  |    O.K.    |    O.K.       |
5  |    Error2  |    Error2     |
6  |    O.K.    |    O.K.       |
7  |    O.K.    |               |
8  |    O.K.    |               |
---|------------|---------------|----------
9  |    Error2  |      0        |
10 |            |               |
```

---

In `Row 9` in the above sheet I want to display the latest `Error` from the column.

In `Cell A9` I use this formula for it:

```
=LOOKUP(2;1/(A1:A8<>"O.K.");A1:A8)
```

It works without any issue.

---

However, when I copy the formula to `Cell B9` I get `0` as a result. 
I assume the issue is caused by the empty cells `B7:B8`.

How do I need to modify the formula so it also works when there are empty cells in the range?

Comment: `1/((A1:A8<>"O.K.")*(A1:A8<>""))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in the comments solution from JvdV is working:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/((B1:B8<>"O.K.")*(B1:B8<>"")),B1:B8)
```